# Bring the IE browser to front

Tags: selenium

I am automating an EBS (Oracle Apps) application using Selenium for the web part and Leanft for the EBS part. In the middle of a test case execution a browser window opens. I want to use the same instance of the Webdriver which is used to login but the problem is it is not in front. How should I bring the existing browser window to the front. Have tried multiple solutions provided on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

To bring back *Selenium*'s **focus** on the *Internet Explorer* browser opened through the *WebDriver* instance forcefully you can use the following line of code:

- *Java* solution:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
  ```
- *Python* solution:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.focus();")
  ```

Comment: Not working . The  code you shared is opening a new window and bringing it to focus.. The IE browser tab is not opened through the WebDriver . It is launched by an operation in the EBS application. Please share your insights

Comment: @Yogesh The line of code wouldn't _...open a new window..._ but bring the webdriver initiated window within the **focus**. If the _The IE browser tab is not opened through the WebDriver_ why are you trying to control the window in the first place through _WebDriver_?

Comment: actually the framework in our enterprise handles web part using Selenium and EBS part using LeanFt. I understand your point but that is what I cant control . Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Yogesh _Selenium_ works on its own principle irrespective of the framework underneath e.g. _LeanFt_, _foo()_, etc. I have provided the canonical solution to regain Selenium's focus. Let me know the feedback.